# Using instance attrs in __init__ signature in Python

Tags: python

Is there any possibility to use internal instance attributes in the signature of a class in Python3? Or if not, what would be the pythonic way to achieve the same effect. What I am thinking of is a signature like this:

```py
  1 class C:
  2     def __init__(self, a=self._b):
  3         self._b = 1
  4         self.a = a
```

so that I can have a default for `a` based on some internal attribute `_b`.

Comment: Can `_b` be a (logically constant) class attribute? Otherwise, there's no good answer (just use a sentinel value like `None` as the default).

Comment: Default value of `None` & check for that inside the method

Answer (score 1):

Specify the default as a class variable, and use that as the default in both places:

```
class C:
    default_a = 1

    def __init__(self, a=default_a):
        self._b = self.default_a
        self.a = a
```

Comment: ugh, you're right, OP's code confused me as to the actual intent.  Rewrote with a class variable.

Comment: either way, `default_a` will be faulty in this way: if it is changed in the class after it is created, the default value in `__init__` will remain the previous one, and not be affected by the change.

The correct thing to do is use a sentinel value (such as None) as the default argument, and assign the class attr to the instance attr based on whether another value was passed or not.